# How to manipulate ::before pseudo element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have a `h2` element in HTML and I want to manipulate the `::before` pseudo element position if the H2 aligned to center. I'm looking for something like this:

```
$(this + '::before').css({
    'left': ($(this).width() - x) / 2
});
```

Is there any working solution?

Comment: jQuery cannot access pseudo elements directly in the manner you're attempting.

Comment: Okay, and is there any way to manipulate with native JavaScript?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333